# Djikstra method using cppRouting package in R

Tags: r, shortest-path, dijkstra

I would like to know how to use the dijikstra method using cppRouting package. My database contains distance data between different locations, and I would like to use this method to solve my problem, which is to calculate the shortest paths between those locations. I researched and saw about this package that works with this method.

Package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cppRouting/cppRouting.pdf

```
> df <- read_excel('C:/Users/Local.xlsx')
> df
# A tibble: 6 x 6
         `Local 1`      `Loca 2`    `Local 3`     `Local 4`      `Local 5` `Local 6`
          <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>
1            0           350.         1279.         1544.         2393.         2837.
2          350.            0          1365.         1807.         2605.         3159.
3         1279.         1365.            0           946.         1386.         2433.
4         1544.         1807.          946.            0           918.         1502.
5         2393.         2605.         1386.          918.            0          1483.
6         2837.         3159.         2433.         1502.         1483.            0
```

Comment: Could someone please give me a light?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input data is a graph.
A graph is a set of vertices (or nodes) connected by edges.
A graph is commonly used to symbolize a network like roads, where edges are road segment and nodes are intersections. The graph is weighted if each edge have a weight, describing distance or travel time.

See this trivial example of directed graph, let's assume that all edges are of equal length  :

[image: graph]

In R and cppRouting package, the graph must be a data frame describing each edges :

```
library(cppRouting)
library(igraph)

graph<-data.frame(from=c(0,1,2,3,4,2),
                  to=c(1,2,3,0,2,4),
                  weight=c(1,1,1,1,1,1))

#visualize 
test<-graph_from_data_frame(graph,directed = TRUE)
plot(test,edge.arrow.size=0.2)
```

Now, if you want to know the shortest path between node 0 and 3 :

```
cpp_graph<-makegraph(graph,directed=TRUE)
get_path_pair(cpp_graph,from="0",to="3")
```

if you want to know the shortest distance :

```
get_distance_pair(cpp_graph,from="0",to="3")
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer vlarmet.

Answer (score 1):

I'm the author of cppRouting package. The primary data for calculating distances or paths is a graph and you don't provide it, do you have one ?

You read some distance matrix I guess but what is your input data ? road network ?

Please read [this](https://github.com/vlarmet/cppRouting/blob/master/README.md) to know how to use cppRouting package.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Could you provide me with a generic database so I can see what input data is mostly needed ?? Thank you again!